# How to get URLParams in Angular v16

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Here is my routing configuration, and I would like to access the URL parameter like `class` and `instance` within the `instanceNavigatorComponent`. However, I am currently getting 'undefined' in the console.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: 'expert',
    component: ExpertDialogComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'instances',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
      
      {
        path: 'instances',
        component: InstancesComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: ':class',
            component: InstanceNavigatorComponent,
          },
          {
            path: ':class/:instance',
            component: InstanceNavigatorComponent,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },

];
```

And here is the `instanceNavigatorComponent`:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    
        this.router.paramMap.subscribe((params) => { //router is ActivatedRoute
          const classParam = params.get('class');
          const instanceParam = params.get('instance');
          console.log('Class parameter:', classParam);
          console.log('Instance parameter:', instanceParam);
        });
}
```

Comment: Try `this.route.firstChild.paramMap.subscribe((params) =>` instead of `this.router.paramMap.subscribe((params) =>`

Answer (score 1):

I am glad you asked that because Angular 16 add this awesome feature that you can access url params like a simple `@Input`.
To enable it you need to add a simple thing:
where you bootstrap your application you need to add `withComponentInputBinding()` function call, like that:

```
bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes, withComponentInputBinding())]
});
```

in this on place you can simply get your url params like `@Input`

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'ewfefewfwefewf',
  template: '',
})
export class InstanceNavigatorComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() class!: string; // this takes the value from the url class param !!!
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('this class variable, from url:', this.class);
  }
}
```

in this way you can for example access the `class` variable you declare in the routes.

this is a [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rhag2u?file=src%2Fmain.ts) where you can try it

hope it's clear :)

Comment: But how can I detect if url is changed?

Comment: @NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      bindToComponentInputs: true,
    }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}

Comment: same as `@Input` - every change is render the component again

Comment: because in ngOnInit I can get just initial value of params

Comment: ```@NgModule({ imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { bindToComponentInputs: true, }), ], exports: [RouterModule], }) export class AppRoutingModule {}```

I added this in my routing.module but it seems doesn't work properly

Comment: caveat: only works with top level routes

Comment: @AndrewAllen what do you mean "top level"?

Comment: @EliPorush routed components aka component used inside your lazy loaded configuration. But not its children (unless you have paramsInheritanceStrategy set)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are calling paramMap on a Router instance and not on a ActivatedRoute instance. Therefore your code should look like this:

```
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

 ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
   if (params) {
    const classParam = params.get('class');
    const instanceParam = params.get('instance');
    console.log('Class parameter:', classParam);
    console.log('Instance parameter:', instanceParam);
   } 
  })
 }
```

Let me know if it worked.